# the items in ListView.builder not change (The ListView.builder is not rebuilding) after setState in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list item I review it in the ListView.builder
I need to change background Color of item by index I put Color  as item in my list
and try to change it by index on click  and onPressed
I put the set State and its change the color of items but the ListView.builder  is not rebuilding

```
SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
            child:   ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: textmonth.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return  OutlinedButton(
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.black,
                      backgroundColor: textmonth[index].Colrs,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (kDebugMode) {
                        print(textmonth[index].Colrs.toString()); //Color(0xffffffff)

                      }
                      setState(() {
                        textmonth[index].Colrs = const 
                      });
                      print(textmonth[index].Colrs.toString()); //Color(0xff000000)
                    },
                    child:  Text(lang
                          ? textmonth[index].NameEN
                          : textmonth[index].NameAR),

              );
            },
          ),
          ),
```

The problem has been resolved

He updates the list and makes it again to build it again with the old data because I defined the list in the BuildContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the content of the array at an index but you didn't change the reference to that object.

Simply:

```
setState(() {
  textmonth[index].Colrs = const Color(0xff000000);
  textmonth = List.from(textmonth);
});
```